# How can I use visibility timeout as a "retry" mechanism?

Tags: amazon-sqs

My use case is that I have a queue from which my application reads messages. I need to delete the message if it is processed correctly, else I want it to stay in the queue. If my application processes the same message again, does that count as a "retry" based on which `maximum receives` works, or does maximum receives work as a different metric? if i cannot use it as a retry, can you help me with how I could go around implementing it?

Really sorry about the crude ideas I have compiled, but I am a newbie in terms of AWS, and wanted this done a bit quicker than expected.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can you take a look on **dead letter queues**. When a message generate an unexpected error it can be retried according to **maxReceiveCount**, if there is still an error after all allowed retries then message will be moved in a dead letter queue according to **redrive policy** :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Hope this helps.